# Header not fixing in firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

My website header not fixing in the top in firefox. https://www.ruralserver.com, its header bottom is not working fine. It's working fine on Chrome.

I have already tried this code:

```
.site-header .bottom {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: #434d54;
    background-image: none;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: auto auto;
    height: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It is working on all other browser without making any changes. but not working on Firefox. so please help on this. open website link on chrome and than in Firefox to show different.

Comment: check your style sheet (line no. 577) ".site-header .top" and replace "position:relative" with "position:fixed", hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use position:fixed

```
.top {
  position: fixed;
  top:0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
  background: #374147;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
```